# Application of a basis of the Lie algebra on the Lie exponential

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, matrix-exponential

Let $G$ a compact connected (matrix) Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. Let $\{E_i\}$ be a basis of the Lie algebra thought as a vector space. Any element of the Lie group $G$ can be written as $e^X=\exp(a^iE_i)$ for some $X \in \mathfrak{g}$.
For any Lie group there exists a left action $\lambda : \mathfrak{g} \times G \xrightarrow{} G$ given by $\lambda(X,p)=\exp(X)p$. So it is possible to define a map $\lambda_* : \mathfrak{g} \xrightarrow{} \mathcal{H}(G)$ from the Lie algebra to the algebra of vector spaces over $G$. Such map is defined as:
$$
\lambda_* (X)(p):=\frac{d}{dt} \lambda(tX,p) |_{t=0}
$$
for any $p \in G$.

It is possible to show that, in the case of a matrix Lie group, such a map is the multiplication map i.e.

$$
\lambda_*(X)(p)=Xp
$$
where $Xp$ is the matrix multiplication.

I'm wondering if there is some nice formula for
$$
E_i e^X=\lambda_*(E_i)(e^X)
$$
In the case of a matrix Lie group the exponential map is the matrix exponential. Moreover, because $G$ is compact the Lie group exponential coincide with the Riemannian exponential w.r. to the Levi-Civita connection of any bi-invariant metric of $G$.

I have tried to expand the exponential, but I can't see any possible simplification.

There is some way in which such element can be expressed in terms of commutators of the Lie algebra?

If the answer is no, is there some way in which it can be expressed in terms of the Levi-Civita connection?

Comment: What is E_i(e^X)? What exactly do you mean by generators of the Lie algebra (for the usual meaning of that your claim is false)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry i corrected my notation and clarify what i meant.
The generators of the Lie algebra are a bases for the Lie algebra, as usual.
$E_i(e^X)$ is simply the matrix multiplication in the case of a matrix Lie group. In general is the map $\lambda_*$ that i have now defined

Comment: Generators of a Lie algebra are usually that: generators of a Lie algebra. If you want a basis of the Lie algebra (that is, generators of the vector space underlying the Lie algebra!) say so, as it is much clearer.

Comment: Are you also assuming $G$ is connected? Otherwise not every element can be written on the form $e^X$.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim RIght, i forgot to include this hypotesys